# Filter rendered cells with DataTables.net

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

i made a Table that uses [Datatables](http://datatables.net) as plugin for managing all the table functions (sorting, searching, etc)
i got a "NOTE" fields that is renderend adding extra html to the text, like

```
NOTE FIELD (ORIGINAL): "Hello"
NOTE FIELD (RENDERED): "<span class='fancyClass'>Hello</span>"
```

everything works fine, but i'd like to filter the table to all the elements in the table where "fancyClass" exists.

I've been trying with several solutions, like simple click event on the button that has to perform the search, istantiating the click event on the the "initComplete" event of the datatables and so on.
the problem is that every path i took, gaves me the same original text, with no HTML, or class.
i've tried iterating rows, columns or either cells, with data() or renderer(), with no luck.

This is the part where i try to find the data:

```
 api = $('#dataTable').dataTable().api();
 api.rows({page:'current'}).every(function (v,i) {
 console.log("CELLS ",this.cells(v,index).render());
 });
```

anyone got tips?

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: This is the part where i try to find the data
`api = $('#dataTable').dataTable().api()
          api.rows({page:'current'}).every(function (v,i) {
            console.log("CELLS ",this.cells(v,index).render());
          })`

Comment: pls add your code as part of your question. And since you have something working its best to show it in a JSFIDDLE so we can help you better